# Wordpress and Static content

Tags: html, wordpress, .htaccess

Can I serve static (.html) content from the same directory as a wordpress install. Where the static content is to replace some of the existing content in wordpress. We only want to remain using wordpress for maybe 2 sections of our site. We have otherwise created static pages for everything else.

I am thinking we can do some htaccess magic to get done what is ultimately desired. Which is replacing example.com/index.php (the "home") with index.html for example, while leaving the rest of the blogcentric views open to using index.php

is this possible or am I wrong in assuming I can lay over wordpress in this fashion?

Comment: Yes you can have static HTML files. No alteration to code nor `htaccess` files

Comment: if I understood correctly you can just make a folder at root and serve html from there. you can then create a redirect if you need to make the landing page from that root folder.

Comment: I want to serve html files less the extension. In the same directory as wordpress root, so I can seamlessly serve wordpress content through wordpress using the same url schema, basically without having to create a "blog" subdirectory. to put wordpress in. The pages today, already exist in Wordpress, but. We are breaking certain sections out that are more static in nature into HTML outside of wordpress, to get rid of some of the wordpresss overhead on those pages.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, very possible to serve static from the same directory. Easy way would to be to create a home (or name whatever you want to be used as url) directory within the root directory of the WP install. Now when you go to yoursite.com/home it will serve the index.html, but shouldn't include the filename.

EDIT: also if you edit your wp_options table in your database and set the home option to http://yoursite.com/home it should act as your homepage.

Hope this helps!